# Run a cron job every minute, but starting at specific time

Tags: cron

Im trying to set up a cron job that would run every minute between 9:45 am and 4pm on weekdays.

Easy to get it to work between 9am and 4pm, but getting it to start at 9:45 is causing me issues.

I've tried:

`45/1 9-16 * * 1-5`

But that returns an error, 16: bad minute

Answer (score 3):

Breaking it up into two cronjobs should work...

```
45-59/1 9 * * 1-5 /path/to/script
*/1 10-16 * * 1-5 /path/to/script
```